# Why does fxml variable doesnt work when i use it from array as reference?

Tags: java, variables, reference, javafx

I was lazy and i decided to add bunch of listeners onto my controls in loop.Bud i noticed that when i use fxml variable from field

```
@FXML
private TextField profileNameField = new TextField();
```

and add handler to it

```
profileNameField .setOnKeyReleased(new CustomEventHandler(profileNameField, l1) {

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexes[0],
                    Pattern.DOTALL);

            Matcher matcher;

            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {

                System.out.println("handling");
                String text = this.control.getText();
                matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

                if (matcher.matches()) {
                    verifyed();
                } else {
                    failedToVerify();
                }
            }

        });
```

Everything works.
Bud when i put bunch of them into array

```
 private TextInputControl[] textControls = {
        profileNameField,....
```

and using reference

```
textControls[0].setOnKeyReleased(new CustomEve..
```

All of the sudden there is no effect. Why is that? I port my application from swing everything worked there bud javafx seems to be little differend in this aspect.This is not that big of a deal i already did it the NON-lazy way.And my fx application works perfectly bud out of curiosity,**Why does it behave like this, can anyone explain?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define it in this way:

```
@FXML private TextField profileNameField = new TextField();
```

the assigned value is never user and will be rewritten by FXMLLoader.
So the array is initialized with incorrect values, initialize it after `profileNameField` is initialized by FXMLLoader, in the `initialize` method (yep, I think, the English should be edited in this answer :) ):

```
public class <Controller name> implements javafx.fxml.Initializable { // necessary
    ...
    private TextInputControl[] textControls;
    @FXML private TextField profileNameField;
    ...
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        textControls = {
                profileNameField,
                ...
        };
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers

Comment: I understand.Thanks for fast answer!